# Phonegap php header redirect not working in android

Tags: php, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

It works in the desktop browser though.

Here is the code:

```
        var options = {
            clearsessioncache: "yes",
            clearcache: "yes"
        };

        data = {};

        url = "test.php"

        var ref = window.open(url,'_blank','location=no,toolbar=no,hidden=yes','closebuttoncaption=Return');
```

And I also have code that runs injected via executescript on loadstop.

This works in the desktop browser. The user clicks the button and is redirected as follows in **test.php**:

```
header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

However, it fails while running in android. The page stays blank and no redirect occurs. Any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: Php not wotk because android not have php interpreter

Comment: @Naumov this makes no sense because the php code is ran in the server

Comment: @Fane two things. 1) Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005).  2) Are you aware that both [Google and Apple frown on apps](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a) that are website wrappers?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 1) Yes, but i'm merely implementing third party authentication in my application, so it should still read PHP redirects if it is inAppBrowser 2) Yes, but maybe it is suitable for my needs 3) Can you help me or will you just be a condescendent intellectual? :))

Comment: @Fane *"condescendent intellectual"* is you feeling insulted because your app may be reject. You should get over that and decide if you really want to do this app. If so, i can help. Otherwise, you might consider another line of work. Writing software is not for those that get their "feeling hurt" when facts are presented.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Thanks. So, can we get to the point of my question? I'm pretty sure that is what stack overflow is for. I am using 'inAppBrowser' of phonegap but it simply is not reacting to the php redirect, that's about it. Any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: Very good. Thanks for responding to my questions. I may have you answer after these questions. Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the *Phonegap Desktop App*? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in your original post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the php doesn't work on mobile devices because it's server side language but not client side. Now, the javascript redirect isn't working because it needs to add the "[Cordova Whitelist Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)" in your config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.1.0" />
```

Or simply

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.1.0" />
```

After that trying putting the following in your config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

is the path to your HTML file inside the source directory.

```
<access origin="*" />
```

will allow you to redirect to any of the external page using JS. If you want to restrict your app to just a single domain then use it like this.

```
<access origin="http://yourdomain.com" />
```

At the end, put the following intents

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Comment: All those things were included in config.xml. As I said, it worked on the browser while debugging phonegap, it fails in the phonegap app for android. The problem must lie in something else...

Answer (score 0):

You should provide absolute path of test.php page.(If I am not wrong, your php page will be in your server)

```
        var options = {
            clearsessioncache: "yes",
            clearcache: "yes"
        };

        data = {};

        url = "http://yourserver.com/test.php"

        var ref = window.open(url,'_blank','location=no,toolbar=no,hidden=yes','closebuttoncaption=Return');
```

Comment: this is not the problem, I said it worked on the desktop version

Comment: @Fane If I am not wrong your desktop version should be hosted in the same server and thus it is working fine with relative path. But when you are creating app, your app doesn't know the base url of the server and so you need to provide absolute url. Change the url to absolute URL and check it once.